# split a string into list

Tags: string, list, usb, tcl

I am developing a tool for devcon using TCL. My problem is that  I have a string from this format for example:

```
USB\VID_16A6&PID_3000\1030FG5295
```

which describe a USB device ID, and I would like to either get list:

```
[USB VID_16A6&PID_3000 1030FG5295]
```

or somehow extract the last part of the string (`1030FG5295`).

I tried to use TCL's string and scan without any success. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split in the backslash and get the last element of the resulting list (the `split` part gives a list containing each part):

```
set last_part [lindex [split $input_string {\\}] end]
```

Or use a regex:

```
regexp -- {[^\\]+$} $input_string last_part
```

Or since it's almost in a file path format, use a file command:

```
set last_part [file tail $input_string]
```

In any of the 3 cases, you get a variable called `last_part` which contains `1030FG5295`.

There are probably some other ways (`string range` is another I can think of) but those are the ones I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that `scan` would be an appropriate tool, but you need the right pattern.

```
set input_string {USB\VID_16A6&PID_3000\1030FG5295}
scan $input_string {%[^\]\%[^\]\%[^\]} a b c
puts "a=$a b=$b c=$c"
# a=USB b=VID_16A6&PID_3000 c=1030FG5295
```

The key is that we use `%[^\]` instead of `%s`, to exclude `\` as it is a separator, and we put the pattern in `{`braces`}` instead of `"`double quotes`"` so Tcl doesn't interpret it as a meta-character.

---

You can also use `split` (which works nicely with `lassign`):

```
lassign [split $input_string "\\"] a b c
```

Here, I've given an explicit separator and doubled up the backslash because otherwise Tcl will get a bit confused. (It's in double quotes for highlighting reasons; it's not actually necessary.)